# ROS execute multiple commands from file

Tags: ros

Is there any way to run these commands consecutively automatically?

```
roscd stereo_camera
rosparam load marvin_cameras.yaml
rosrun stereo_camera stereo_camera __name:=bumblebeeLeft
rosrun stereo_camera stereo_camera __name:=bumblebeeCenter

roslaunch openni_launch_marvin kinect_left.launch
roslaunch openni_launch_marvin kinect_center.launch
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to try [http://answers.ros.org/questions/](http://answers.ros.org/questions/).
I'd say the main problem is that rosrun and roslaunch block the terminal, right? Therefore, some forking might solve it.

Comment: @Humungus - Why suggest someone goes outside of Stack Exchange when we have our very own [*robotics* site](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ros) here?

Comment: @MarkBooth True, I've missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write a single launch file which runs your desired nodes/launch-files with delays as stated [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/233353/set-delay-between-starting-nodes-within-launch-file/?answer=285852#post-id-285852), or you can just write a bash script which should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
roscd stereo_camera
rosparam load marvin_cameras.yaml
rosrun stereo_camera stereo_camera __name:=bumblebeeLeft &
rosrun stereo_camera stereo_camera __name:=bumblebeeCenter &
roslaunch openni_launch_marvin kinect_left.launch &
roslaunch openni_launch_marvin kinect_center.launch &
wait
```

Assuming that your script is named `script.sh`, you have to make it executable via `chmod +x script.sh` and then run it via `./script.sh`.
The `&` signs send the commands to the background, while the `wait` command waits until all programs in the background finished.

Comment: I suggest single roslaunch file as well as it gives you more control over nodes and also logging outputs